# How come I cannot use a VMDK disk on with a Windows 7 guest on another machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I am a bit baffled about what I just tried to do.  I have a machine running Windows 8.1.  I have VirtualBox installed. Let's call this MACHINE-A.  On MACHINE-A I have a VirtualBox Guest that runs off of an External USB 3 drive (EXT-DRIVE) with an external VMDK virtual hard disk.  This is a Windows 7 Guest.  It runs great.

Now I have a new machine running Windows 10 that also has VirtualBox installed.  Let's call that MACHINE-B.  I hooked up the EXT-DRIVE to MACHINE-B.  I used Disk Configuration to map the EXT-DRIVE to use the same drive letter that EXT-DRIVE uses on MACHINE-A.  (Drive W:)

Then, on MACHINE-B, I setup a VirtualBox Guest using almost the EXACT same settings of the virtual machine on MACHINE-A using the same Virtual Hard drive (VMDK) that is on the EXT-DRIVE.

However, when I attempt to start the new guest on MACHINE-B I am getting a Windows Boot error.  It says something about Hardware changing, lists the fix options, and then says "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible".

I was surprised at this.  I thought the new guest on MACHINE-B would work out the partitions automatically. But it is like it isn't finding the System Reserved partition.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: It sounds like the virtual hardware presented on the two platforms is different. Do you have the same BIOS/Firmware virtualization features enabled on both hosts? have you tried loading the existing guest from machine-a on machine-b instead of creating a new VM and attaching the shared disk?

Comment: Frank, I am not sure how to load an existing guest.  I thought what I did was my only way to do it.  How d o you do that?  As for your hardware question. MACHINE-A is a 5+ year old i7.  MACHINE-B is a brand new (6th gen) i7.  Both machines have the BIOS Virtualization Extensions enabled.  I am pretty sure that the settings on each guest are identical.

Comment: the easiest way is to export it as an appliance on Machine-A, and then import it into the machine-b. https://software.grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=13838